# Turn the cell in a table into a clickable link to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, hyperlink, filtering

So here's the first table

```
  |Location     |product    |
 1|Bob's place  | carrot    |
 2|Alan's place | banana    |
 3|Bob's place  | strawberry|
 4|Chris's place| oranges   |
```

The second table

```
  |Location     |product    |
 1|Bob's place  | carrot    |
 2|Bob's place  | strawberry|
```

I've already made both pages.

I just want to click on "Bob's place" and everything that isn't Bob's place gets filtered away.
And same effect if I click on "carrots", every entry that isn't carrots gets filtered out.

Is there any easier way to do this?

Bare in mind, new data is going to be introduced at the top of the table, what was line 1 will become line 2.

Comment: As I was writing the question, it was originally "how do I turn every cell into a link to a different page

Comment: Then I realised I should be asking if that's the best way to achieve what I want.